# On clicking on bar chart display list of related records on Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, visualforce-charting

I have a visualforce page with a bar chart that displays a user count on x-axis and profile name on y-axis. When a user clicks on the bar chart, I need to populate the user data in a table that have that particular profile. Any help is appreaciated

Comment: welcome to SFSE, please take somoe time to visit [ask] and take the [tour], once you have done so, pelase **[edit]** your post with what your problem is, and where you are stuck. We expect you to have already done some research when posting here (best effort at least), and include a specific problem, if you have developed some code, please include it in your post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no Click event available on the Visualforce Chart. But you can use the rendererFn attribute of [apex:chartTips](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_chartTips.htm) to extend the **onhover** function to fire custom JavaScript events.

In the below example, I have used an `apex:actionFunction` to populate the user details whenever the user hovers on the Bar Chart.

Controller

```
public class BarChartController {
    List<User> users;
    String profileName{get;set;}

    public List<User> getUsersDetail() {
        users = [SELECT u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email FROM User u Where u.profile.name = :profileName];
        return users;
    }
    public void updateUserDetails(){
        profileName = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('profileName');
    }
    public List<BarChartData> getUsers(){
        List<BarChartData> lstUsers = new List<BarChartData>();
        for(aggregateresult a :[SELECT u.profile.name name, COUNT(u.id) n FROM User u WHERE u.profile.name !=null Group By u.profile.name LIMIT 10]){
            lstUsers.add(new BarChartData(a));
        }        
        return lstUsers;
    }
    public class BarChartData{
        public  integer recordCount{get;set;}
        public string profileName{get;set;}
        BarChartData(AggregateResult result){
            this.recordCount = (Integer) result.get('n');
            this.profileName = (String) result.get('name');
        }       
    }
}
```

Page

```
<apex:page controller="BarChartController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:chart height="400" width="400" data="{!users}">                    
                    <apex:axis type="Category" position="left" fields="profileName" title="Profile Name"/>
                    <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="bottom" fields="recordCount" title="User Count" minimum="0" maximum="20" />
                    <apex:barSeries orientation="horizontal" axis="left" xField="recordCount" yField="profileName">
                        <apex:chartTips height="20" width="230" rendererFn="renderChartTip"/>
                    </apex:barSeries>     
                </apex:chart>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="usrdetail">
                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!usersDetail}" var="usr">
                    <apex:column value="{!usr.firstName}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!usr.lastName}"/>            
                </apex:pageblockTable>  
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:actionFunction action="{!updateUserDetails}" name="getuserdetail" reRender="usrdetail">
                <apex:param name="profileName" assignTo="{!profileName}" value="" />
            </apex:actionFunction>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
    function renderChartTip(obj, item) {
        var yField = item.yField;
        var m = item.storeItem;
        this.setTitle('Check below table for more details');
        getuserdetail(m.get('profileName'));
    }
    </script>    
</apex:page>
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your prompt response. I tried using above controller and vf page code but I am not able to display barchart on the vf page, only user table is displayed. Any thoughts on this? Thanks

Comment: @LearningMacro I found that in some cases if the profile name is null the Bar chart will not work. So I have updated my answer by adding a condition in the code as `WHERE u.profile.name !=null`. Hope it will solve your issue. If it will work, please mark it as answer.